# R: Alter values in a row based on values in row above

Tags: r, mapply

I asked a similar question before but it appears I was not clear enough. I have a data.frame with 32 columns. I want to create a duplicate row below each row that meets this certain criteria

```
df$resting == "toolong".
```

Following suggestions from DWin I have accomplished this using the following code.

```
df[ unlist(mapply( rep, rownames(df), 1+(df$resting=="toolong"))) , ]
```

That works well enough but now I need to alter some of the values of the "parent" row **AND** the newly created duplicate row. The variables **action** and **time** for the parent rows needs to be set to

```
action <- "for"
time <- 60
```

The duplicate rows need to have the variables **action** and **time** set to

```
action <- "l" # which is what it is already so this can be ignored for now
time <- "parent row time" - 60 # I am unsure how to code this.
```

Here is an example data.frame that shows the structure of the data (there are many more columns in the original database).

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
resting <- c("f","toolong","t","f","f","toolong","t","f","toolong","t")
time <- c(23,145,34,16,17,134,67,89,123,12)
act <- c("f","l","f","d","d","l","f","d","l","d")
df <- data.frame(id, resting, time, act)
```

Here is what the final df should look like.

```
    id resting time act
1    1       f   23   f
2    1 toolong   60   for
2.1  1 toolong   85   l
3    1       t   34   f
4    1       f   16   d
5    2       f   17   d
6    2 toolong   60   for
6.1  2 toolong   74   l
7    2       t   67   f
8    3       f   89   d
9    3 toolong   60   for
9.1  3 toolong   63   l
10   3       t   12   d
```

Thanks, Tim

Comment: I explained how to do this in response to your request in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used character vectors (as I described in the earlier answer):

```
df <- data.frame(id, resting, time, act, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df2 <- df[ unlist(mapply( rep, rownames(df), 1+(df$resting=="toolong"))) , ]
> df2[ df2$resting=="toolong" & !duplicated(df2) , "act"] <- "for"
> df2[ df2$resting=="toolong" & df2$act == "for" , "time"] <- 60
> df2[ df2$resting=="toolong" & df2$act == "l" , "time"] <- df2[ df2$resting=="toolong" & df2$act == "l" , "time"] - 60
> df2
    id resting time act
1    1       f   23   f
2    1 toolong   60 for
2.1  1 toolong   85   l
3    1       t   34   f
4    1       f   16   d
5    2       f   17   d
6    2 toolong   60 for
6.1  2 toolong   74   l
7    2       t   67   f
8    3       f   89   d
9    3 toolong   60 for
9.1  3 toolong   63   l
10   3       t   12   d
```

Comment: thanks for your patience. I have been hitting my head against a wall for a while on this one and you answered the question and dealt with my R ignorance in a stand up fashion.